# Rotacionar imagem em torno do próprio centro

Tags: c#, bitmap, rotação

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e gostaria de saber como rotacionar livremente uma *bitmap* que está desenhada em uma *pictureBox* sem rotacionar toda _pictureBox_e de modo que a *bitmap* **rotacione em torno do seu próprio centro**. Segue minha última tentativa:

```
Bitmap irisref1;

private void pcbREFOLHOS_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(pcbREFOLHOS.Width / 2, pcbREFOLHOS.Height / 2);
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(contador);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(irisref1, new PointF((5 - atualdata1 - 2.5f) * 10, 0));
    contador++;
    //e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.White, 3), 0, 0, 150, 60);
}
```

Desta maneira não obtive o resultado esperado, pois a imagem "orbita" em torno do ponto especificado, porém eu gostaria que a imagem girasse em torno de seu próprio centro. Alguém pode ajudar com esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente implementar o seguinte método:

```
public static Bitmap RotateImageN(Bitmap b, float angle)
{
    //Create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image.
    Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
    //Make a graphics object from the empty bitmap.
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
    //move rotation point to center of image.
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width / 2, (float)b.Height / 2);
    //Rotate.        
    g.RotateTransform(angle);
    //Move image back.
    g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width / 2, -(float)b.Height / 2);
    g.DrawImage(b, 0,0,b.Width, b.Height);
    return returnBitmap;
}
```

Depois só precisará fornecer o `Bitmap` e o ângulo que pretende rodar a imagem, pegando depois no resultado.

---

Mais detalhes na questão [Rotating image around center C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431345/rotating-image-around-center-c-sharp) disponível no **SOen**.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou muito bem, porém a imagem de acordo com o tempo de execução vai ofuscando. Não estou conseguindo parar isso.

Comment: Estranho, não tinha conhecimento dessa "consequência". Mas este código não me parece que esteja a provocar isso... tem mais algum código para além deste para tratar a imagem?

Comment: Não, somente o evento paint da "pcbREFOLHOS".

Comment: E ainda necessita desse evento? Pode apagar o conteúdo, certo?

Comment: Eu estava utilizando o evento Paint pois a imagem vai ficar rotacionando durante o tempo de execução.

Comment: Tentei adicionar um timer, pra ficar rotacionando e dando "Invalidate()", porém continua ofuscando.

Comment: Segundo as indicações nesta questão do **SOen** [Image in PictureBox Become Blurry While Rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510307/image-in-picturebox-become-blurry-while-rotating), deve utilizar sempre a imagem original, alterando apenas a rotação acumulada. O _blur_ deve-se a um efeito inevitável da rotação.

Comment: Agora sim, 100% amigo, muito obrigado!!